# Samsung ProXpress m3870fw printer keeps jamming

Tags: printing, printer, paper, paper-tray

I have Samsung ProXpress m3870fw.
Half the times I try to print, there is a jam. Sometimes I just have to open the papers tray and remove the jammed paper, and sometimes the jam is on the rear.

I am using A4 80-gram paper.

I tried to remove all the removable parts of the printer and see if there is a paper that stayed there and causes to the jam, but there was nothing.

There is something to do?

(Sorry if my English grammar is not very good...)

Thank's!

Comment: How old is it? After a while the pickup/transfer roller surfaces get shiny & lose their grip. For a while you can clean them but eventually they will harden & need replacing.

Comment: It's pretty old... How do I clean them?

Comment: high percentage Isopropyl alcohol; using it with a microfibre cloth might just nicely roughen up the surface too. If the rollers are totally shot it won't work, though. You'll need replacements [or often, cheaper to buy a new machine].

Comment: There is a video that explains how to do that?

Comment: I have no idea. The manual should have take-apart & cleaning instructions.

Comment: OK, thank you very much!